# What causes prototype variables to show up when using "for in"?

Tags: javascript

I know you [should avoid it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742), thus although annoying I always protect myself against it.

But what exactly causes extensions to a prototype to show up when using "for in"? Sometimes it is (or seems to be) safe to use "for in" and other times it isn't.

## i.e.:

I'm talking about for example:

```
Array.prototype.last = function(){ return this[this.length-1]; }
```

Showing up as:

```
for(var k in someArray){
    console.log("%o %o", k, someArray[k]); // eventually outputs "last 'function(){ return this[this.length-1]; }'
}
```

Comment: You have a stray `"` there that I am not sure where it should go...

Comment: What causes it? Nothing really... it happens because [the spec says so](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) ("Enumerating the properties of an object includes enumerating properties of its prototype...")

Comment: What do you mean by you "protect" yourself against it? Do you mean `hasOwnProperty`? If so, that's still the wrong way to iterate an array. There's nothing wrong with extending `Array.prototype` in your own code, as long as you loop properly.

Comment: jQuery's `.forEach` shouldn't be reaching items on `Array.prototype`, but it will get enumerable items from `Object.prototype` when looping objects. If you have enumerable properties on `Object.prototype`, you should fix it.

Comment: @thesystem (accidentally deleted the last comment sry) yeah I know, but I was curious on why it happens when.

Comment: `for...in` should never be used with an `Array`, period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

`for in` loops over all enumerable properties, including those inherited from the prototype.

Comment: +1 maybe you should mention something about how `hasOwnProperty` can be used to avoid "inherited" properties if a `for...in` loop is required.

Answer (score 3):

As SLaks said, it's by design. What determines if a property (inherited or not) will show in a `for..in` loop is its [[Enumerable]] internal attribute. If it's true, the property will show, otherwise it won't.

Every property has such an attribute (and a few others). It can be checked using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor). For example, considering your `Array.prototype.last` method:

```
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, "last");
```

It will return an object like this:

```
{
configurable: true,
enumerable: true,
value: function (){ return this[this.length-1]; },
writable: true
}
```

You can change the value of [[Enumerable]] with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to hide it from `for..in` loops:

```
descriptor.enumerable = false;
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "last", descriptor);
```